Checkout step in Azure Pipelines is giving Smudge downloading error when LFS is set to true
I have in my Azure Pipeline, checkout step with lfs:true in my release branch.
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  lfs: true

When the build runs, it gives the following error.

Error downloading object:
/Path/to/DLL file (31a4c7b): Smudge
error: Error downloading
/Path/to/DLL file
(31a4c7bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):
batch response: Expected json type, got: "text/plain; charset=utf-8"

The trouble is when I run the same checkout for master branch in another pipeline, it works fine. Any suggestions or possible directions?


Are the contents of your release branch and main branch consistent? 2. Create a new branch based on main and run checkout with lfs set to true and check if there is the same issue. 3. Are you using a self-hosted agent or a MS-hosted agent?


I am using self hosted agent


Have you tried to create a new branch based on master and run checkout with lfs set to true? What's the result? 2. Try to run git lfs checkout on your local machine to checkout your release branch and check if it has the same error or not. 3. Try to run git lfs pull in a CmdLine@2 task in your pipeline instead of using checkout step. Will it have the same error? Based on the current information, it's not sure whether there is a problem with the files in your release branch or the pipeline. It is recommended to try these to narrow down the issue.


Okay, I will try them and revert

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT 1. I created a new branch off master and tried checkout with lfs set to true. The large files get downloaded properly. Then I created another new branch off the release branch and tried checkout with lfs set to true. Large files do not download. 2. When I tried git lfs checkout on my local machine, I get Skipped checkout for "/path/to/DLL/file", content not local. Use fetch to download message. I get this Skipped checkout.. message for the same 92 files that I am seeing when I run my Azure pipeline where it says LFS object not found: [404] LFS object not found

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT 3. I also tried this: - task: CmdLine@2   inputs:     script: |       git checkout /name/of/release/branch       git pull       git lfs pull but I get `git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
credential-manager-core
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://xxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/_git/xxxxxxxx/'` error


You also encountered the same error in local checkout. Other branches can be successfully checked out. Based on the current situation, it seems that there are some problems with the lfs file in your release branch. You can try to reconfigure the lfs in your release branch. If your release branch can be successfully checked out before, you may also consider reverting your release branch to the last working commit using git reset --hard <the hash of the commit>

We inherited the source code from another company several months ago, so I am not sure if the release branch was successfully checked out before. I would like to think that yes, it must have happened and that is how they must have been able to do a prior release to clients, but I have no way of knowing the details about that. Sorry, I am trying to seek clarity on what you mean when you say try to reconfigure the lfs in your release branch. Your assistance is appreciated.

See how to configure lfs from this doc git lfs and Manage and store large files in Azure repo.

I ran git lfs checkout on my local machine. I got Skipped checkout for "/path/to/DLL/file", content not local. Use fetch to download message for 92 files that I was having trouble with, and it listed all the 92 files. I went to master branch, downloaded these 92 files and uploaded them to my release branch. I ran the build, but it still did not pull the lfs files. Finally, I deleted the entire contents of the s folder which the pipeline uses while running and ran the build again. This time it worked like a charm and pulled all the lfs files correctly
